# Python simultaneous assign only from some elements of a list

Tags: python, assignment-operator, simultaneous

In Python I can do this

```
w,x,y,z = (1,1,2,3)
```

But suppose I only need the values of x and y. Is there a way to only simultaneously assign a few variables (while still keeping the beautiful simultaneous assignment syntax?). I'm hoping to find something along the lines of MATLAB's tilde operator

```
~,x,y,~ = (1,1,2,3)  # This is not valid Python code
```

I'm aware that I can just define a dummy variable to do this,

```
d,x,y,d = (1,1,2,3)
```

But I am curious if there is a special operator just for this purpose.

Comment: Traditionally, "don't care" variables in python are named `_` or `__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, the appropriate way to do what you are doing is to actually make use of the '_' as your "throwaway" variable. So, you are very close in what you are doing. Simply do this:

```
_, x, y, _ = (1,1,2,3)
```

Here is some information on the single underscore character:

[What is the purpose of the single underscore "_" variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)